# Should the DC-DC and solar charging go through the main fuse or dedicated fuse?

Tags: battery-charging, automotive, 12v, fuses, solar-charge-controller

I am planning a 12V dual battery setup to be used in a car. The aux battery is a LiFePo4 battery and it will be charged via a combined DC-DC and solar charger (50A, fuse 65A).

I want to add a fuse and switch or a circuit breaker as first element close to the aux batteries positive port. Behind that sits a fuse box (60A). Later the buse box might put behind a connection bar. But right now it's the only consuming branch.

Should I put everything behind a main fuse:

- Battery

  - Main fuse and switch or circuit breaker

    - Fuse

      - Fuse box
    - Fuse

      - Charger

Or bypass switch and fuse for charging:

- Battery

  - Fuse and switch or circuit breaker

    - Fuse

      - Fuse box
  - Fuse

    - Charger

#### Side questions for calculating the main fuse

What voltage should the calculations based on? Just 12V or should I considder that the actual range is somewhere maybe between 11V and 15V?

I am a bit confused if I should add the charging and discharging amps to get the value for the main fuse. In my simple understanding I would assume that at least in the first setup charge from the charger would directly go through the consuming fuse box and not the main fuse. So securing the circuit with the higher amp might be enough?

[image: dual battery diagram]

Thanks

Comment: There is a good reason why EEs choose to draw schematics.

Comment: Generally, working on automotives should be done by certified persons. The reason beeing: Insurance companys will use every straw in case of bigger problems. Showing, that your changes did not interfere with the ABS will cost you a pretty dollar and the insurance company has 2+ extra years (Sounds silly? Yeah, i agree. Mr. Insurance with performance benefits doesn't).... There are enough services happy to make the updates you want!

Comment: I added the diagram as suggested.
Regarding professional services. Yes, that is a valid discussion, thanks for pointing that out. But without propper context that is hard to reason, and this question is not the place to have that.

Comment: The fuse is to protect the wiring. Whenever you have a decrease of conductor size, then you must have a fuse to protect that conductor. There are online tables for ‘ampacity’ of various wire sizes. Basically it is ensuring the wire never gets got enough to damage the insulation.

Comment: @Kartman Yes, I find the amacity charts helpfull to choose the wiresize. Here I try to figure out why it is sometimes suggested to connect the charger directly to the battery. Bypassing the positive bus. And if not - meaning keeping the charger at the same connection as the fuse box. How much amps do I get max at the battery (main fuse)? Do charging and discharging amps  just add up?

Comment: We have no idea what your ‘charger’ is, so we can’t answer. If your solar cell wiring is 3mm sq, then you won’t be getting 50A of charge current. So the amps won’t be ‘adding up’. Speak to the people that sold you the equipment - they will know what you are referring to.